# -|- arrow pointing in the wrong direction

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

### Issue

The `-|-` arrow is intersecting another node to its left. I want it to point eastward,
then point northward, then point westward. How do I change this arrow's direction? I have
looked through the **Tikz** and the **Tikz-cd** manuals, but I have struggled to solve
this issue.

Note that the arrow starts at `store: d` and ends at `[for] search new (x)`. Here is
what the arrow looks like:
[image]

---

### Code

The issue is located in `\graph [use existing nodes]` at `nM -> [dashed, vh path] nK; nN2 -> [dashed, -|-] nF;`, under `\matrix[row sep=5mm, column sep=5mm]`. The macros for `-|-` is located in `\begin{tikzpicture}` at `-|-/.style=...` Here is a simplified version of my
code isolating the issue:

```
%---[ load packages ] - document format
\documentclass[10pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%---[ load packages ] - page format
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titling, titlesec, fancyhdr}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    textwidth=420pt,
    top=38mm,
    bottom=38mm,
}

%---[ load packages ] - graphics presentation
\usepackage{tikz, pgf}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning, graphs, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\ttfamily}}}

%---[ document ]
\begin{document}
%---[D-graphics] block
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[S]
\begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[nonterminal/.style={rectangle, minimum size=4mm, rounded corners=1mm, fill=grey!10},
                            >={Stealth[round]}, thick, black!90,
                            every new ->/.style={shorten >=1pt},
                            bend left/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
                            bend right/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
                            hv path/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
                            vh path/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
                            -|-/.style={to path={
                                (\tikztostart.east) -| ($(100.east)+(0.5,0)$) |- (\tikztotarget.east)}},
                                graphs/every graph/.style={edges=rounded corners}
            ],
            \matrix[row sep=5mm, column sep=5mm] {
                % row 01
                \node (nA) [anchor=west, nonterminal, fill=black!90, text=white, minimum width=2cm] {begin}; & & & & \\
                % row 02
                \node (nB) [anchor=west, nonterminal, minimum width=2cm, draw=black!90] {instruct}; & & & & \\
                % row 03
                \node (nC) [anchor=west, nonterminal, minimum width=2cm, draw=black!90] {start}; & & & & \\
                % row 04
                & \node (nD) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {inputs}; & & & \\
                % row 05
                & \node (nE) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {$d = sum - x$}; & & & \\
                % row 06
                & \node (nF) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {[for] search new (x)}; & & & \\
                % row 07
                & \node (nG) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {[for] search old (y)}; & & & \\
                % row 08
                & & \node (nH) [anchor=west, nonterminal, fill=blue!30!green!35] {[if]}; & & \\
                % row 09
                & & & \node (nI) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {$x \text{!=} y$}; & \\
                % row 10
                & & & \node (nJ) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {$x \text{==} y$}; & \node (nJ2) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {$d = sum - y$}; \\
                % row 11
                & \node (nK) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {[for] search old (z)}; & & & \\
                % row 12
                & & \node (nL) [anchor=west, nonterminal, fill=blue!30!green!35] {[if]}; & & \\
                % row 13
                & & & \node (nM) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {$z \text{!=} d$}; & \\
                % row 14
                & & & \node (nN) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {$z \text{==} d$}; & \node (nN2) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {store: $d$}; \\
                % row 15
                \node (nO) [anchor=west, nonterminal, minimum width=2cm, draw=black!90] {print}; & & & & \\
                % row 16
                \node (nP) [anchor=west, nonterminal, minimum width=2cm, draw=black!90] {update}; & & & & \\
                % row 17
                & \node (nQ) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {[while] user input y/n}; & & & \\
                % row 18
                & & \node (nR) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {yes}; & \node (nR2) [anchor=west, nonterminal, minimum width=2cm, draw=black!90] {start}; & \node (nR3) [anchor=west, nonterminal, minimum width=2cm, draw=black!90] {print}; \\
                % row 19
                & & \node (nS) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {no}; & \node (nS2) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {terminate}; & \\
                % row 20
                \node (nT) [anchor=west, nonterminal, fill=black!90, text=white, minimum width=2cm] {end}; & & & & \\
            };
            \graph [use existing nodes] {
                % begin
                nA -> nB;
                % instruct function
                nB -> nC;
                % start function
                nC -> [distance=2mm, vh path] {nD, nE, nF, nG, nK}; nF -> nG -> nK;
                nG -> [vh path] nH;
                nH -> [distance=2mm, vh path] {nI, nJ}; nJ -> nJ2;
                nI -> [dashed, vh path] nG;
                nK -> [vh path] nL;
                nL -> [distance=2mm, vh path] {nM, nN}; nN -> nN2;
                nM -> [dashed, vh path] nK; nN2 -> [dashed, -|-] nF;
                % print function
                nC -> nO;
                % update function
                nO -> nP;
                nP -> [vh path] nQ;
                nQ -> [distance=2mm, vh path] {nR, nS}; nR -> nR2 -> nR3; nS -> nS2;
                nR3 -> [dashed, vh path] nQ;
                % end
                nP -> nT;
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[E]
\end{document}
```

Comment: i could not compile this code -- what is 100.east for example

Comment: You've simplified a bit too much. If you test your example you'll find that the `float` package is missing for `H`, `amsmath` is missing for `\text`, the `calc` library is missing for coordinate calculations, you've used the undefined colour `grey` (should be `gray`), and only then do we get to the real problem: that you've used the node name `100` in your definition of `-|-`, which should probably be `\tikztostart` instead.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I do have those packages you mentioned, but I removed them to simplify the code above. However, I was not aware that those packages were essential to Tikz. I used them for other tasks. Thank you for bringing this to my attention. Also, about the `100.east`: I originally had `\tikztostart`, but I was experimenting with the macros to figure out how to fix the issue in question. LoL.

Comment: They have nothing to do with TikZ, but they are required to run your example without error! Simplified examples are nice, but as I said you simplified too much, so that those testing your code first have to fix errors that you introduced.  (On the other hand, `extsizes`, `inputenc`, `blindtext`, `titling`, `titlesec` and `fancyhdr` packages, as well as the `figure` and `center` environments, are all irrelevant for the example I think, so those could all be removed, if you wanted to simplify more.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

having removed the `100.east` and modifying the `-|- style` -- using only a line extending `east` for `0.5,0` which then goes up to join the target seems to suffice -- also removed `H` option in figure –- as also the color grey was creating an error hence used `black!10` instead

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%---[ load packages ] - page format
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titling, titlesec, fancyhdr}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    textwidth=420pt,
    top=38mm,
    bottom=38mm,
}

%---[ load packages ] - graphics presentation
\usepackage{tikz, pgf}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning, graphs, arrows.meta, calc}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\ttfamily}}}

%---[ document ]
\begin{document}
%---[D-graphics] block
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[S]
\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[nonterminal/.style={rectangle, minimum size=4mm, rounded corners=1mm, fill=black!10},
                            >={Stealth[round]}, thick, black!90,
                            every new ->/.style={shorten >=1pt},
                            bend left/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
                            bend right/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
                            hv path/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
                            vh path/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
                            -|-/.style={to path={
                                (\tikztostart.east)-- ++(0.5,0) |- (\tikztotarget.east)}},
                                graphs/every graph/.style={edges=rounded corners}
            ],
            \matrix[row sep=5mm, column sep=5mm] {
                % row 01
                \node (nA) [anchor=west, nonterminal, fill=black!90, text=white, minimum width=2cm] {begin}; & & & & \\
                % row 02
                \node (nB) [anchor=west, nonterminal, minimum width=2cm, draw=black!90] {instruct}; & & & & \\
                % row 03
                \node (nC) [anchor=west, nonterminal, minimum width=2cm, draw=black!90] {start}; & & & & \\
                % row 04
                & \node (nD) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {inputs}; & & & \\
                % row 05
                & \node (nE) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {$d = sum - x$}; & & & \\
                % row 06
                & \node (nF) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {[for] search new (x)}; & & & \\
                % row 07
                & \node (nG) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {[for] search old (y)}; & & & \\
                % row 08
                & & \node (nH) [anchor=west, nonterminal, fill=blue!30!green!35] {[if]}; & & \\
                % row 09
                & & & \node (nI) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {$x$}; & \\
                % row 10
                & & & \node (nJ) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {$x $}; & \node (nJ2) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {$d = sum - y$}; \\
                % row 11
                & \node (nK) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {[for] search old (z)}; & & & \\
                % row 12
                & & \node (nL) [anchor=west, nonterminal, fill=blue!30!green!35] {[if]}; & & \\
                % row 13
                & & & \node (nM) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {$z$}; & \\
                % row 14
                & & & \node (nN) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {$z$}; & \node (nN2) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {store: $d$}; \\
                % row 15
                \node (nO) [anchor=west, nonterminal, minimum width=2cm, draw=black!90] {print}; & & & & \\
                % row 16
                \node (nP) [anchor=west, nonterminal, minimum width=2cm, draw=black!90] {update}; & & & & \\
                % row 17
                & \node (nQ) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {[while] user input y/n}; & & & \\
                % row 18
                & & \node (nR) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {yes}; & \node (nR2) [anchor=west, nonterminal, minimum width=2cm, draw=black!90] {start}; & \node (nR3) [anchor=west, nonterminal, minimum width=2cm, draw=black!90] {print}; \\
                % row 19
                & & \node (nS) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {no}; & \node (nS2) [anchor=west, nonterminal] {terminate}; & \\
                % row 20
                \node (nT) [anchor=west, nonterminal, fill=black!90, text=white, minimum width=2cm] {end}; & & & & \\
            };
            \graph [use existing nodes] {
                % begin
                nA -> nB;
                % instruct function
                nB -> nC;
                % start function
                nC -> [distance=2mm, vh path] {nD, nE, nF, nG, nK}; nF -> nG -> nK;
                nG -> [vh path] nH;
                nH -> [distance=2mm, vh path] {nI, nJ}; nJ -> nJ2;
                nI -> [dashed, vh path] nG;
                nK -> [vh path] nL;
                nL -> [distance=2mm, vh path] {nM, nN}; nN -> nN2;
                nM -> [dashed, vh path] nK; nN2 -> [dashed, -|-] nF;
                % print function
                nC -> nO;
                % update function
                nO -> nP;
                nP -> [vh path] nQ;
                nQ -> [distance=2mm, vh path] {nR, nS}; nR -> nR2 -> nR3; nS -> nS2;
                nR3 -> [dashed, vh path] nQ;
                % end
                nP -> nT;
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------[E]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The error for the grey color is that you have to use the spelling `gray`

Comment: @js-bibra Thanks for the help. You make this look so easy. Anyways, take care.